# How do I get applescript to work with Preview in Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, applescript, preview

How do I get applescript to work with Preview in Snow Leopard? I'd like, for instance, my applescript for resizing a window to full screen (which works for most applications (e.g., chrome)) to work for preview.

In old versions of OS X (as ghoppe points out), one can enable this by typing

> defaults write
>   /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/Info
>   NSAppleScriptEnabled -bool YES

into a terminal. This doesn't seem to work in Snow Leopard.

Comment: Please be more precise

Comment: Agreed with @radius. What does this question mean? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: You should describe with more details what you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited it to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Does [this help](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=19696)? Preview is not really that scriptable.

For what it's worth, [Automator can do image manipulation](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2010/01/batch-resize-images-with-automator.html) more easily, it also has some PDF actions.

If you're wanting to do image manipulation with Applescript, what you're really looking for is [Image Events](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/imageevents/index.html), not Preview.